# Routing error with default url in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a routing problem in an MVC 6 web application : when I set route parameter in the controller used by default, application send a 404 error.

My routing configuration :

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

My dashboard controller (application works) :

```
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
     public DashboardController()
     { }

     [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult Index() => View(new IndexViewModel());
}
```

Same dashboard controller (application responds a 404 error) :

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
     public DashboardController()
     { }

     [HttpGet]
     [Route("[action]")]
     public IActionResult Index() => View(new IndexViewModel());
}
```

Comment: What url are you using that returns the 404?

Comment: The default url when I lanch the application, http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/

Comment: @Adrien: Please don't use asp.net-mvc and asp.net-mvc6 tags. Former is for the old ASP.NET MVC Framework and later one is wrong, since the ASP.NET Core MVC got it's version reseted to 1.0.0

Comment: @Tseng Ok, noticed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this is occurring is that routes specified via `routes.MapRoute` only apply to controllers that are **not** using attribute based routing.  Since your second example is using attribute based routing that controller can only be reached via the route specified in the attribute.  So it can only be reached at /Dashboard/Index